# SSIS Bug - Flow Components going blank

Tags: ssis

Every time I change tabs in SSIS or minimize/maximize the program, every node loses everything but its text, making it very hard to follow the diagrams.  The image/border/etc. returns when I click on a node.

[image: (image)]

Has anyone else experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the package once *(every time I open the project)* appears to fix this.